# objection circular dependency and typescript definitions

Tags: typescript, circular-dependency, objection.js

There are two object in our datamodel that refer to each other, on database level each "client" owns some "scopes" (`HasManyRelation`). And each "scope" has many "clients" that are allowed access (`ManyToManyRelation`). The objection models would look a bit like:

```
import {Model, ModelObject} from "objection";
import {OauthClientUriModel} from "./OauthClientUriModel";
import {OauthScopeModel} from "./OauthScopeModel";

export class OauthClientModel extends Model {

    id!: number;
    static get useLimitInFirst(): boolean {
        return true;
    }
    static get tableName(): string {
        return "oauth_client"
    }

    static get idColumn(): string {
        return "id";
    }


    name!: string;
    static get NameColumn(): string {
        return "name";
    }

    _scopes!: ModelObject<OauthScopeModel>[]|null;
    static get relationMappings() {
        return {
            _scopes: {
                relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
                modelClass: OauthScopeModel,
                join: {
                    from: 'oauth_client.id',
                    to: 'oauth_scope.owner',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `_scopes!: ModelObject<OauthScopeModel>[]|null;` is there to give typescript information in the returned queries.
Now in the scopes object we need to be able to access all clients that are allowed to access it.

```
export class OauthScopeModel extends Model {

    id!: number;
    static get useLimitInFirst(): boolean {
        return true;
    }
    static get tableName(): string {
        return "oauth_scope"
    }

    static get idColumn(): string {
        return "id";
    }
  
    name!: string;
    static get nameColumn(): string {
        return "name";
    }

    owner!: number;
    static get ownerColumn(): string {
        return "owner";
    }

    _allowed_clients!: ModelObject<OauthClientModel>|null;
    static get relationMappings() {
        return {
            _allowed_clients: {
                relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
                modelClass: OauthClientModel,
                join: {
                    from: 'oauth_scope.id',
                    through: {
                        from: 'oauth_scope_client.scope',
                        to: 'oauth_scope_client.client'
                    },
                    to: 'oauth_client.id',
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

This, however leads to an error with circular imports:

`_allowed_clients` is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation at the statement

`_allowed_clients!: ModelObject<OauthClientModel>[]|null;`

How would I prevent this circular import while still maintaining strong type safety? (So not making one of the arrays have `any` type).